# c# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, formatexception

After having Ctrl+Alt+E to see every possible exceptions, I have seen the following error:
    Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

on the method SampleSolution:

```
private void SampleSolution(DbSet<CapitalisationActuelle> cap, DbSet<DonneesDUMP> don, DbSet<Resultat> res)
    {
        foreach (var donneesDump in don)
        {
            if (!cap.Any(c => c.PMRQTOTM == donneesDump.PMRQTOTM))
            {
                var result = cap.Any(c => don.Any(c1 => c1.PMRQTOTM == c.PMRQTOTM));
                var ress = res.SqlQuery("INSERT INTO " + cnn.Resultat + " (NomTable,Groupe_D_Alerte,NomChamp,TOTMPMRQ,SiModifie,LibelléTOTAvant,LibelléTOTApres,Remarque) VALUES 'CapitalisationActuelle', '" + donneesDump.Groupe_Alerte + "', 'PMRQTOTM', '" + donneesDump.PMRQTOTM + "', '', '', '', 'Ajoute'");


                cnn.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

On line

```
var result = cap.Any(c => don.Any(c1 => c1.PMRQTOTM == c.PMRQTOTM));
```

I have the error "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list." and the troubleshooting tips: "When converting a string DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object" and "Make sure your method arguments are in right format".

Last information, the [PMRQTOTM] is the primary key of table CapitalisationActuelle and DonneesSDIN, cannot be Null and is a Varchar(50) Data Type.

I don't understand what my error mean, neither what can I do to solve'it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Add a breakpoint to your method and debug your code. Step through each line until execution breaks and then you'll know what line causes the problem. The error message is clear and if you're not using anything directly with an `index` parameter, then one of your called methods must be.